# Spring Integration JDBC metadata store

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-integration, metadata

I am using Spring Integration to read files `FileReadingMessageSource` and in order to avoid the same file to be read twice (or other concurrent apps read it also), I am using `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`.

Everything works well, it persists the state of the file in DB (MySQL). 
The problem is : when I try to read the same file twice I get an exception:

`org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.getSharedInstance()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService;`

Is there anyone who faced the same? 
Thanks!

DETAILED EXCEPTION:

```
SEVERE: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.getSharedInstance()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService;
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.SingleColumnRowMapper.<init>(SingleColumnRowMapper.java:53)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.getSingleColumnRowMapper(JdbcTemplate.java:1291)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:797)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.metadata.JdbcMetadataStore.putIfAbsent(JdbcMetadataStore.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.accept(AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractFileListFilter.filterFiles(AbstractFileListFilter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter.filterFiles(CompositeFileListFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultDirectoryScanner.listFiles(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:86)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.scanInputDirectory(FileReadingMessageSource.java:293)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive(FileReadingMessageSource.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:175)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:173)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:299)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.getSharedInstance()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService;` means that you use incompatible Spring Integration and Spring Framework versions. For Spring Integration you should just rely on the transitive dependencies. Or even better just use Spring Boot dependency management.

Comment: Thanks @Artem, I see You are right. I am using WatchServiceDirectoryScanner to watch for new coming files but when I changed the version from 4 to 5 in order to use JdbcMetadataStore the WatchServiceDirectoryScanner is not eligible anyway. Am I missing something?

Comment: it's all ok. I didn't see that the class is deprecated in the latest version. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, it was **dependency problem** for me too. Versions were conflicting when I saw libraries list in project directory.
- I was using Spring-Security(4.2.5) along with Spring framework(4.2.5) in my project.
- Maven was downloading **"spring-jdbc"** and **"spring-tx"** dependency ***(4.3.15)*** version of library in build.
  Rest all dependencies were 4.2.5 by default.
- *So I added maven dependency of* **"spring-jdbc" to (4.2.5) manually in pom.xml**, *which fixed the issue.*